# Why Akka-Http still uses older Akka-Actor?

Tags: maven, akka, akka-http

I have added the latest akka-http to my project but that includes the very old 2.4.19 version on akka-actor. Hence I also added akka-actor version 2.5.4 to the dependency. However, that results into following error:-

```
Detected java.lang.NoSuchMethodError error, which MAY be caused by incompatible Akka versions on the classpath.
```

My maven config is like below:-

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-http_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-actor_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

What am I missing? Is there any version of akka-http which uses the latest akka-actor?

**Update: Added dependency graph**

[image: Dependecy graph. Note 10.0.9 includes actor 2.4.19 not the latest]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Compatibility Guidelines](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/compatibility-guidelines.html) page in the documentation:

> Akka HTTP 10.0.x is (binary) compatible with *both* Akka `2.4.x` as well as Akka `2.5.x`, however in order to facilitate this the build (and thus released artifacts) depend on the `2.4` series. Depending on how you structure your dependencies, you may encounter a situation where you depended on `akka-actor` of the `2.5` series, and you depend on `akka-http` from the `10.0` series, which in turn would transitively pull in the `akka-streams` dependency in version `2.4` which breaks the binary compatibility requirement that all Akka modules must be of the same version, so the `akka-streams` dependency MUST be the same version as `akka-actor` (so the exact version from the `2.5` series).
>
> In order to resolve this dependency issue, you must depend on akka-streams explicitly, and make it the same version as the rest of your Akka environment....

Change your Maven dependencies to the following:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-actor_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Explicitly depend on akka-streams in same version as akka-actor -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-stream_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-http_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. I missed this.