# Conflicting Akka versions when using Akka / Akka Streams / Akka HTTP

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm trying to build a project using Scala 2.12.3, sbt 0.13.6, and the following library dependencies in my build.sbt file:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.5.4",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.5.4",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream-testkit" % "2.5.4" % Test,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.0.9",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-core" % "10.0.9",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.1" % Test)
```

However, I keep getting the following warning about version conflicts...It appears that `akka-http` has a transitive dependency on Akka / Streams version 2.4.19.  I found a recent similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903422/why-akka-http-still-uses-older-akka-actor/45905521#45905521), which advises to explicitly add akka-streams as a dependency and make sure it's the same version as akka-actor.  Here are the dependency warnings:

```
[warn] Found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are 
suspected to be binary incompatible:
[warn] 
[warn]  * com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.12:2.5.4 is selected over 
2.4.19
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-http-core_2.12:10.0.9       
(depends on 2.4.19)
[warn]      +- com.werner.opttech:dependency-test_2.12:0.0.0      
(depends on 2.4.19)
[warn] 
[warn]  * com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.12:2.5.4 is selected over 
2.4.19
[warn]      +- com.werner.opttech:dependency-test_2.12:0.0.0      
(depends on 2.5.4)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.12:2.5.4           
(depends on 2.5.4)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-parsing_2.12:10.0.9         
(depends on 2.4.19)
```

Any advice on how to resolve this error, so that I can use the latest versions of akka, akka streams, and akka http? Thanks!

Comment: It will only resolve the dependencies without any warnings if I remove the dependencies on both akka-actor and akka-streams, but in that case, I would be stuck on akka 2.4.19, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chunjef's answer is correct.If you want to clear the warning indeed,add the following code to your build.sbt.

```
conflictManager := ConflictManager.strict

dependencyOverrides += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.5.4"

dependencyOverrides += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.5.4"

dependencyOverrides += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % "2.12.3"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your configuration is correct, as it follows the [compatibility guidelines](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/compatibility-guidelines.html) that you mentioned. I think you're misinterpreting the warning messages as errors; you *are* using the 2.5.4 version of those libraries. Take a closer look at this snippet:

```
[warn]  * com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.12:2.5.4 is selected over 2.4.19
```

sbt is indeed picking version 2.5.4 of the `akka-actor` library instead of version 2.4.19.

Also, running `show update` in the sbt console outputs the following:

```
[info]  com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.12
[info]          - 2.5.4
[info]                  status: release
[info]                  publicationDate: Thu Aug 10 09:17:00 EDT 2017
....
[info]          - 2.4.19
[info]                  evicted: true
[info]                  evictedData: latest-revision
```

sbt evicted version 2.4.19 of `akka-actor` in favor of version 2.5.4.

The warning messages actually confirm that you're working with the current version of the Akka tools.

Comment: Yeah, I could see it was evicting 2.4.19 for 2.5.4, but because of the warnings I wasn't sure if I would be causing any new issues.  Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

Kind of related:
akka-http 10.1.0-RC1 [removes the transient dependency](https://akka.io/blog/news/2017/12/22/akka-http-10.1.0-RC1-released):

> we changed the policy not to depend on `akka-stream` explicitly any more but mark it as a `provided` dependency in our build. That means that you will have to always add a manual dependency to `akka-stream`.